# Galois group of $x^p-a$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of Sym$(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: galois-theory

This is a question from BAI, Jacobson:
Assume that $x^p-a \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible. Then the Galois group of $x^p-a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of Sym($\mathbb{Z}_p$) of the form $y \mapsto ky+l$ where $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $k \ne 0$.

How do I go about this ?

Comment: The best way to show a map is a bijection is to write down its inverse.

Comment: What is BAI, please?

Comment: Basic Algebra I: Jacobson, Nathan. Basic algebra. I. Second edition. W. H. Freeman and Company, New York, 1985. xviii+499 pp. ISBN: 0-7167-1480-9 MR0780184

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help: if $\;b\;$ is a root of that polynomial and $\;\zeta:=e^{2\pi i/p}\;$ , then all the roots of the polynomial are $\;b,\,b\zeta,\,b\zeta^2,\,...,b\zeta^{p-1}\;$, and we get both that the Galois group of the given polynomial acts transitively on these set of roots and its order divides $\;p!=\text{Sym}\,(\Bbb Z_p)\;$  .

Observe also that if $\;\sigma\;$ is one of these automorphisms, then

$$\sigma b=b\zeta^k\;\implies \sigma^n(b)=b\zeta^{N_{\sigma,k}}$$

with $\;N_{\sigma,k}\;$ an integer which can be considered modulo $\;p\;$ and it depends both in $\;\sigma\;$ and in $\;k\;$, for example: since a splitting field for the polynomial is $\;\Bbb Q(b,\zeta)\;$ , any automorphism is determined by its action on both $\;b\,,\,\zeta\;$ . For example we can take

$$\begin{cases}\sigma b=b\\{}\\
\sigma\zeta:=\zeta^2\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies \sigma b\zeta^{p-1}=b\left(\sigma\zeta\right)^{p-1}=b\zeta^{2p-2}=b(\zeta^p)^2\zeta^{-2}=b\zeta^{-2}=b\zeta^{p-2}$$

Observe that $\;\zeta^{2p-2}\to\zeta^{-2}\;$ is in fact done applying arithmetic modulo $\;p\;$ in the exponent. Generalize.